# How do I create internal x padding for an Entry?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an Entry `input_field` and I'm trying to create some internal x padding for the Entry so when you input a value the characters aren't so close to the left side of the Entry.

**My code:**

```
from tkinter import *

screen = Tk()

input_field = Entry(font=("Calibri", 16, "bold"), width=25,).pack()

screen.mainloop()
```

**My output:**

[image]

**I would like something like this:**

[image]

I have tried to use `ipadx` into the .pack() method but simply doesn't change. I've also looked through documentation and found no other replacements to `ipadx` except `padx` but this only creates external padding around the Entry.

Is there a way to create internal x padding instead of manually adding in spaces?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Tkinter Entry pad text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51822820/python-tkinter-entry-pad-text)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ttk.Entry and configure the Style like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk

root = tk.Tk()
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('My.TEntry', padding=(20,0, 0,0))
#padding = (padx left, pady up,padx right,pady down)

widget = ttk.Entry(root, style='My.TEntry')
widget.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yep, as suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60617340/6045800

Comment: yeah all works well, my bad didn't see that answer on that question earlier.